# Why does VSCode show the inherited class doc string when there is a doc string defined in the class

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to understand why when I hover over a class that I created I see the inherited doc string, I would like to see the doc string I put in my class.

Here is my example code:

```
>>> from threading import Thread
>>>
>>> class A:
...     """ My doc string for class A"""
...
>>> class B(A):
...     """ My doc string for class B"""
...
>>> class C(Thread):
...     """ My doc string for class C"""
...
>>> test_1 = A()
>>> test_2 = B()
>>> test_3 = C()
>>>
>>> print(A.__doc__)
 My doc string for class A
>>> print(B.__doc__)
 My doc string for class B
>>> print(C.__doc__)
 My doc string for class C
>>>
```

The example code works as I would expect, however the same code in VSCodes pop up shows the parent Thread class doc string when hovering over the C class:
[VSCode showing parent class doc string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IwHX.png)

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is normal, the `Thread` class has the following parameter definition code:

```
def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs=None, *, daemon=None):
        """This constructor should always be called with keyword arguments. Arguments are:

        *group* should be None; reserved for future extension when a ThreadGroup
        class is implemented.

        *target* is the callable object to be invoked by the run()
        method. Defaults to None, meaning nothing is called.

        *name* is the thread name. By default, a unique name is constructed of
        the form "Thread-N" where N is a small decimal number.

        *args* is a list or tuple of arguments for the target invocation. Defaults to ().

        *kwargs* is a dictionary of keyword arguments for the target
        invocation. Defaults to {}.

        If a subclass overrides the constructor, it must make sure to invoke
        the base class constructor (Thread.__init__()) before doing anything
        else to the thread.

        """
```

When making a call the documentation for the prompt parameter is preferred. If you mouse over the definition, you can see that it shows its own documentation.

[image]

As a test, you can add the following parameters for class `A`. You can see the difference before and after adding:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok that was the part I was missing, the doc string at the top of the class isn't shown, but the doc string in the ```__init__```  is shown. Thanks for showing me how to do it.